# Limitar o número de resultados de uma sub-query com UNION em tempo real para melhoria no desempenho

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Preciso buscar muitos valores que necessitam de duas query's com condições diferentes. Para fazer isso eu uso um `UNION`, mas preciso setar um limite de resultados.

Hoje isso está funcionando com um `limit` e `offset` como é mostrado no final do exemplo, mas esse limite só é tratado quando a query interna terminam, e isso está degradando a performance da aplicação, pois na consulta interna são retornados resultados na casa de milhões.

O limite de paginação que eu preciso é de `50` resultados. Como eu poderia aplicar o limite na consulta interna?

Exemplo da query (resumida):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
        SELECT
            values
        FROM table
            LEFT JOIN table on vl1 = vl2
        WHERE
            conditions

        UNION

        SELECT
            values
        FROM table2
            LEFT JOIN table2 on vl1 = vl2
        WHERE
            conditions

    ) as res 
WHERE conditions LIMIT 0, 50
```

Edit, query completa:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_comprovacoes
            (
                SELECT
                    pcoordenacao,
                    concodigo AS codigo, 
                    IF(concompetenciames IS NULL OR concompetenciames = '00', conlancamento, CONCAT(concompetenciaano, '-', concompetenciames,'-15')) AS data, 
                    pcodebito AS debito,
                    conapagar,
                    conagente AS agente, 
                    icovalortotal AS valor, 
                    icocodigo,
                    'Não material' AS movimento, 
                    concolaborador AS colaborador,
                    pconome,
                    claplanodeconta,
                    pcodebito,
                    clanome,
                    clacodigo,
                    concentrodecusto AS centrodecusto,
                    IF(concompetenciames IS NULL OR concompetenciames = '00', DATE_FORMAT(conlancamento, '%d/%m/%Y'), CONCAT(concompetenciames, '/' ,concompetenciaano)) AS competencia,
                    -- Guarda a requisicão da conta vinculada ao reqcodigo;
                    conrequisicao
                FROM
                    itens_conta
                    LEFT JOIN conta ON icoconta = concodigo
                    LEFT JOIN requisicao ON reqcodigo = conrequisicao
                    LEFT JOIN centro_custo AS cec1 ON concentrodecusto = cec1.ceccodigo
                    LEFT JOIN esquema ON esqcodigo = cec1.cecesquema
                    LEFT JOIN usuario_grupo ON cec1.cecgrupo = ugrgrupo
                    LEFT JOIN classificacao ON icoclassificacao = clacodigo
                    LEFT JOIN plano_conta ON claplanodeconta = pcocodigo
                    -- entra na tabela comprovante e filtra os comprovantes que tem a mesma requisição e estão ativos;
                    LEFT JOIN comprovante ON cmprequisicao = reqcodigo AND cmpativo = 1

                WHERE
                    contipo = 'B'
                    AND concodigo IS NOT NULL
                    AND (pcocodigo != 14 AND pcocodigo != 15 AND pcocodigo != 13) 
                    AND icoativo = 1 
                    AND icoconta != 0 
                    AND concentrodecusto != 0 
                    AND icoclassificacao != 0
                    AND conrequisicao != 0  
                    AND ugrativo = 1 
                    -- Filtro para Favorecido (Comprovações), se for ativado != 0 ou = Agente;
                    {$where_comp}
                    AND {$portador1}
                    AND {$sem_fluxo}
                    AND {$where1}
                    AND ugrusuario = '".COD_USUARIO."'
            )
            UNION
            (
                SELECT
                    pcoordenacao,
                    concodigo AS codigo, 
                    IF(concompetenciames IS NULL OR concompetenciames = '00', conlancamento, CONCAT(concompetenciaano, '-', concompetenciames,'-15')) AS data, 
                    pcodebito AS debito,
                    conapagar,
                    conagente AS agente, 
                    icovalortotal AS valor, 
                    icocodigo,
                    'Não material' AS movimento, 
                    concolaborador AS colaborador,
                    pconome,
                    claplanodeconta,
                    pcodebito,
                    clanome,
                    clacodigo,
                    concentrodecusto AS centrodecusto,
                    IF(concompetenciames IS NULL OR concompetenciames = '00', DATE_FORMAT(conlancamento, '%d/%m/%Y'), CONCAT(concompetenciames, '/' ,concompetenciaano)) AS competencia,
                    conrequisicao
                FROM
                    itens_conta
                    LEFT JOIN conta ON icoconta = concodigo
                    LEFT JOIN centro_custo AS cec1 ON concentrodecusto = cec1.ceccodigo
                    LEFT JOIN esquema ON esqcodigo = cec1.cecesquema
                    LEFT JOIN usuario_grupo ON cec1.cecgrupo = ugrgrupo
                    LEFT JOIN classificacao ON icoclassificacao = clacodigo
                    LEFT JOIN plano_conta ON claplanodeconta = pcocodigo
                    LEFT JOIN requisicao ON reqcodigo = conrequisicao
                    -- entra na tabela comprovante e filtra os comprovantes que tem a mesma requisição e estão ativos
                    LEFT JOIN comprovante ON cmprequisicao = reqcodigo AND cmpativo = 1
                WHERE
                    conportador != 0
                    AND concodigo IS NOT NULL
                    AND (pcocodigo != 14 AND pcocodigo != 15 AND pcocodigo != 13) 
                    AND icoativo = 1 
                    AND icoconta != 0 
                    AND concentrodecusto != 0 
                    AND icoclassificacao != 0 
                    AND ugrativo = 1 
                    -- Filtro para Favorecido (Comprovações), se for ativado != 0 ou = Agente
                    {$where_comp}
                    AND ugrusuario = '".COD_USUARIO."'
                    AND {$portador2}
                    AND {$com_fluxo}
                    AND {$where1}
            )
            ORDER BY
                pcoordenacao, pconome DESC, clanome, data
```

Comment: você poderia adicionar também a query completa? Por que talvez a solução pode estar na reorganização das conditions.

Comment: Editei, coloquei a query completa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analisando sua query completa não tem a necessidade de você utilizar o UNION. Repare que os dados selecionados nas duas querys são os mesmos (Seleciona a mesma tabela itens_conta e os mesmos joins).

Portanto se executarmos as querys sem as condições de filtragem serão retornados os mesmos dados.

Virando apenas uma condição lógico do tipo OU. Onde você quer trazer os registros que respeitem as condições da query1 OU que respeitem as condições da query2.

Ficando assim a query final:

```
SELECT
    pcoordenacao,
    concodigo AS codigo, 
    IF(concompetenciames IS NULL OR concompetenciames = '00', conlancamento, CONCAT(concompetenciaano, '-', concompetenciames,'-15')) AS data, 
    pcodebito AS debito,
    conapagar,
    conagente AS agente, 
    icovalortotal AS valor, 
    icocodigo,
    'Não material' AS movimento, 
    concolaborador AS colaborador,
    pconome,
    claplanodeconta,
    pcodebito,
    clanome,
    clacodigo,
    concentrodecusto AS centrodecusto,
    IF(concompetenciames IS NULL OR concompetenciames = '00', DATE_FORMAT(conlancamento, '%d/%m/%Y'), CONCAT(concompetenciames, '/' ,concompetenciaano)) AS competencia,
    -- Guarda a requisicão da conta vinculada ao reqcodigo;
    conrequisicao
FROM
    itens_conta
    LEFT JOIN conta ON icoconta = concodigo
    LEFT JOIN requisicao ON reqcodigo = conrequisicao
    LEFT JOIN centro_custo AS cec1 ON concentrodecusto = cec1.ceccodigo
    LEFT JOIN esquema ON esqcodigo = cec1.cecesquema
    LEFT JOIN usuario_grupo ON cec1.cecgrupo = ugrgrupo
    LEFT JOIN classificacao ON icoclassificacao = clacodigo
    LEFT JOIN plano_conta ON claplanodeconta = pcocodigo
    -- entra na tabela comprovante e filtra os comprovantes que tem a mesma requisição e estão ativos;
    LEFT JOIN comprovante ON cmprequisicao = reqcodigo AND cmpativo = 1

WHERE
    (
        contipo = 'B'
        AND concodigo IS NOT NULL
        AND (pcocodigo != 14 AND pcocodigo != 15 AND pcocodigo != 13) 
        AND icoativo = 1 
        AND icoconta != 0 
        AND concentrodecusto != 0 
        AND icoclassificacao != 0
        AND conrequisicao != 0  
        AND ugrativo = 1 
        -- Filtro para Favorecido (Comprovações), se for ativado != 0 ou = Agente;
        {$where_comp}
        AND {$portador1}
        AND {$sem_fluxo}
        AND {$where1}
        AND ugrusuario = '".COD_USUARIO."'
    )
    OR
    (
        conportador != 0
        AND concodigo IS NOT NULL
        AND (pcocodigo != 14 AND pcocodigo != 15 AND pcocodigo != 13) 
        AND icoativo = 1 
        AND icoconta != 0 
        AND concentrodecusto != 0 
        AND icoclassificacao != 0 
        AND ugrativo = 1 
        -- Filtro para Favorecido (Comprovações), se for ativado != 0 ou = Agente
        {$where_comp}
        AND ugrusuario = '".COD_USUARIO."'
        AND {$portador2}
        AND {$com_fluxo}
        AND {$where1}
    )
```

Comment: Valeu Thiago! consegui adaptar ao código.

Comment: @leonardo Ótimo. Caso veja como uma solução que possa ajudar outras pessoas, sinalize a mesma como correta. Abraço.